# Visual Studio 2013 C# Build Output to File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 at work and I want my C# build output to be saved to a file I've specified. I found Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run which allows me to set build output and build log file verbosity but there's nothing which indicates the path of a build file. I also can't find any such files in `bin` or `obj` folders.

I've also found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx) which has instructions for manually copying build output to a text file. What I want is some way to have that output written to a file automatically, if possible.

[Edit] I'd like to avoid command-line tools (i.e. I want to build in Visual Studio) and I hope to avoid writing a custom logger class.

---

I put a screen cap of the options section I referenced above [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aHjI.png).

Comment: Did you mean path of a build file or the build log file?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to set the Output path property. Do the following:

1. In Solution Explorer right click the project and select `Properties`
2. Select the `Build` tab
3. Enter the path in `Output path:`

[image: Output Path]

Comment: How did this get marked correct. This outputs the entire build to that folder, not the log file. Not to mention that this outputs the release builds to that folder too.

Answer (score 4):

I also couldn't find any option in Visual Studio, but you can use msbuild from console and log the output to a file

```
msbuild MyProject.proj /t:go /fl /flp:logfile=MyProjectOutput.log;verbosity=diagnostic
```

Also have a look here for more options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx

Comment: That could work and I see that the page you linked has some stuff about writing a custom logger class which may get me closer to what I want but I really want to be able to do this directly from the IDE.